# Prime Ideals gotten from homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I am asked to prove that every prime ideal P of a ring R can be obtained as the kernel of a homomorphism to a field.

I know that the kernel of a homomorphism is an ideal. I need to start from an arbitrary prime ideal and show that it is the kernel of a homomorphism. So it would seem that this would not help, since it would be proving something (that it is an ideal) that I am already assuming (the prime ideal).

Could someone please give ideals how to prove this?

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

The projection $R\to R/P$ is a homomorphism of $R$ to a domain, and this map's kernel is $P$.

Integral domains embed in their field of fractions.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see how R/P is an integral domain, but I do not understand its embedding into the field of fractions.

Comment: @violin.lover Then you should [read about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions)